# Create CSS Vertical line with circles and different colors

Tags: html, css

[image: example]

How to create this section with line, circle and different colors

I tried many different ways, lists, spans, more divs, can't align them properly in different colors

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/scratchead/Loam2gju)

```css
* {
  box-sizing  : border-box;
  font-family : Nunito, sans-serif;
  }
.bold {
  font-weight : 700
  }
.container {
  margin : 40px 40px;
  }
@media (min-width: 768px) 
  {
  .container {
    display : flex;
    }
  }
i {
  color    : rgb(9, 121, 105);
  position : relative;
  display  : inline;
  }
.container ul {
  list-style : none;
  margin     : 0;
  padding    : 0;
  position   : relative;
  }
.container ul::before {
  content  : '';
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  width    : 0px;
  height   : 100%;
  border   : 2px solid rgb(9, 121, 105);
  }
.container ul li {
  margin   : 30px 25px;
  position : relative;
  }
.container ul li span {
  content  : '';
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : -25px;
  width    : 0px;
  height   : 100%;
  border   : 2px solid rgb(9, 121, 105);
  }
.first::before {
  content          : '';
  width            : 10px;
  height           : 10px;
  border           : 2px solid rgb(9, 121, 105);
  position         : absolute;
  border-radius    : 50px;
  left             : -7px;
  background-color : rgb(9, 121, 105);
  }
.second::before {
  content          : '';
  width            : 10px;
  height           : 10px;
  border           : 2px solid rgb(9, 121, 105);
  position         : absolute;
  border-radius    : 50px;
  left             : -7px;
  background-color : white;
  }
.third::before {
  content          : '';
  width            : 10px;
  height           : 10px;
  border           : 2px solid rgb(9, 121, 105);
  position         : absolute;
  border-radius    : 50px;
  left             : -7px;
  background-color : gray;
  }
.thirdLine::before {
  content  : '';
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : -25px;
  width    : 0px;
  height   : 100%;
  border   : 2px solid grey;
  }
.container ul li span::before {
  top  : -5px;
  left : -7px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="left-section">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="first"></span></span>
        <div class="a">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-credit-card"></i>
          <p class="bold">Add the virtual card to your mobile wallet</p>
          <p>Head over to Credit Karma Money™ for the How-to</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <span class="second"></span>
        <div class="b">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-sack-dollar"></i>
          <p class="bold">Access your Refund Advance</p>
          <p>Yours to spend before your refund arrives</p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <span class="thirdLine"></span>
        <span class="third"></span></span>
        <div class="c">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
          <p class="bold">Use your card to earn more rewards</p>
          <p>Earn cash back on select debit card purchases</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      </span>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-section">Right Section
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/scratchead/Loam2gju/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Alternative: use a "Range Slider" and set it to vertical, rotate (90deg), then auto disable it via JS body onload....